# How to Add One column value to another coloumn value in bulk in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

We have stock and price columns and we want to add stock number to price columns

For eg.

Stock(Column) 5
Price(Column ) 100

We want it be as below

Price ( Column )
5-100

So Final value for Price should be 5-100

Answer (score 0):

To get the total, click in price cell, and then:

```
Callout 1 On the Home tab, click the Sum button in the Editing group.
Callout 2 A color marquee surrounds the cells in the formula, and the formula appears in price cell.
Callout 3 Press ENTER to display the result in price cell .
Callout 4 Click in price cell to display the formula in the formula bar.
Callout 5 Write there =SUM(Stock cell number,-(Price cell number))
```

[Check this reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/get-to-know-excel-2007-enter-formulas-RZ010074593.aspx?section=5)

Comment: I am not looking for the total.. The Price column should have the value as "5-100" and not -95.. please help